# Equivalent expressions for an open set

Tags: general-topology

I am told:

Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that the following are equivalent:

(i) $D$ is open.

(ii) $D \cap \partial D = \emptyset$

(iii) $D =D \cap(\partial D)^c $

I've done the following:

First, for (i) -> (ii):

Assume $D \cap \partial D \neq \emptyset$. Then, $\exists$ a $p$ such that $p \in D$ and $p \in \partial D$. Consequently, $\exists$ $B_r(p) \notin D$. Hence, D is not open.

Second, for (ii) -> (iii)

I'm somewhat lost here, I think I have to prove that:

(1) $D = D \subseteq (\partial D)^c $ and (2) $D =D \supseteq(\partial D)^c $

However, I'm not quite sure how I can conclude this from (ii).

Finally, for (iii)->(ii)

Let $p \in D$. It follows that $p \in D$ and $p \in (\partial D)^c$ $\Rightarrow$ $p \notin \partial D \Rightarrow B_r(p) \subseteq D$.

This is my first contact with topology so any comments and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (ii) -> (iii), note that

$$D = D \cap \mathbb{R}^n = D \cap (\partial D \cup (\partial D)^c) = (D \cap \partial D) \cup (D \cap  (\partial D)^c)$$

For (i) -> (ii), you mean that $B_r(p) \not\subseteq D$, not $B_r(p) \notin D$. In (iii) -> (i), you should also be explicitly quantify $r$, that is, explicitly say "there exists $r > 0$ such that..." or "$\exists r > 0$ such that...". Otherwise, it looks fine.